# On elliptic operators with non-continuous coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $E, F \rightarrow M$ be two smooth vector bundles over a closed smooth manifold $M$, and $P: \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(F)$ be a linear elliptic differential operator of order 1 with coefficients in $L^p$ for some $p > 2$.

(Actually, in what I have $P$ is smooth outside some set $K\subset M$ of measure zero.)

Is $P$ Fredholm on $W^{k, q}$ for $q\leq p$? If $Pu \in W^{k-1,q}$, does $u$ belong to $W^{k, q}$? Could someone help me with references about this class of operators?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you cannot expect elliptic regularity beyond (perturbations of) $W^{1,2}$ if the leading order coefficient is in $L^{\infty},$ let alone having singularities. You will probably need more information about the structure of the equation and singularity to get a useful answer.